# using the re and urllib.request module

Tags: python, module, urllib

im using python 3.7 and i wanted to write a program that takes name of a city and returns the weather forcast . 
i started my code with :

```
import re
import urllib.request
#https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Tel-Aviv-Yafo/forecasts/latest
city=input("entercity:")
url="https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + city +"/forecasts/latest"
data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read
data1=data.decode("uf-8")
print(data1)
```

but when I wanted to read my data i got this error :

> File 
>          "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
>           result = func(*args)
>           File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
>           raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>           urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>           Process finished with exit code 1

=> can some one help me and tell what is the problem ? 
thanks:)

Comment: Try `print(url)` before opening it, it looks like your URL returns a 404: Not found

Comment: what did you give as the input?

Comment: my input was the city tel aviv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some spelling mistake in the city name you have entered. I tried running the following code

```
 import re
 import urllib2
 city=input("enter city:")
 url="https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + city +"/forecasts/latest"
 data=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
 print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

It works properly when i input

> enter city:'newyork'

While the same code throws `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` error if the input is

> enter city:'newyolk'

You can solve this by using a try-except statement

```
city=input("enter city:")
url="https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + city +"/forecasts/latest"
try:
    data=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
except:
    print('The entered city does not exist.Please enter a valid city name')
```

Comment: it now gives me the eror:C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/p.py
entercity:newyork
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/p.py", line 8, in <module>
    data1 = data.decode("uf-8")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'decode'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I faced the same issue. I solved it by replacing `data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read` with `data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()`

Comment: the problem is that it gives me an eror when i want to use .decode

Comment: I changed `read` to `read()` then it stopped throwing error when i used `decode()`

Answer (score 1):

Tried with `requests` library it worked.

```
import requests

city = input("entercuty:")
url = "https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/"+city+"/forecasts/latest"
data = requests.get(url)
print(data.status_code)
print(data.text)
```

Gave city as "Stuttgart".

> Status code: 200